# FontAwesome - Change Icon colours Latex

Tags: latex, font-awesome-5

came across FontAwesome icon package. When shifting through the documentation I cam across:

```
{\color{color-name} text and/or icon }
```

However, this does not seem to work for me. Anyone know what is the correct format for changing the colour of icons?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[border=0.1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.275\textwidth} % 27.5% of the page width for the first row of icons
    \vspace{-\baselineskip} % Required for vertically aligning minipages
    {\color{Blue} \icon{Globe}{12}{\href{someAddress}{someAdd}}}\\

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]. The syntax you show seems ok. You are loading one of the colour packages, aren't you?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yeah I am, I'm not sure if it has something to do with the minipage? I don't see why it should

Comment: The quote you show does not seem to be from the fontawesome5 documentation. Are you sure you are looking at the documentation of the correct package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- if you want to use `\href`, you must load the `hyperref` package
- you are opening one more `{` than you are closing
- if you want to use an icon from fontawsome5, either use `\fa<insert name here>` or `\faIcon{<insert name here>}`, e.g. `\fGlobe` in your case.

---

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.275\textwidth} % 27.5% of the page width for the first row of icons
    \vspace{-\baselineskip} % Required for vertically aligning minipages
    {\color{Blue} \faGlobe \faIcon{globe} \href{someAddress}{someAdd} }\\

\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, the first two were just error on my part when writting it up on stack. Forgot about the href import.

I have used the \faIcon{globe} before but it doesn't seem to be working. The \faGlobe does however.